# EF Core Migration in Azure Error: : Process completed with exit code 1

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

We have an azure pipeline where we create our ef core migration script and then place it in a folder to be connected with the NuGet package we create.

When we run `script migration -i` on our local computers, it will generate the migration without any issues.

When we run it via our pipeline, we have this error:

```
##[debug]System.Exception: Process completed with exit code 1.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.ProcessHandler.RunAsync()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.TaskRunner.RunAsync()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.StepsRunner.RunStepAsync(IStep step, CancellationToken jobCancellationToken)
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on? We've re-run numerous times. We have other APIs that are working fine.

It started breaking after we updated our repository with some LINQ code. Not sure if that is connected or what?

Here is out setup:

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

I reverted the repository code (changes with LINQ and such) and it built the ef core migration without any issues.

I know someone can't tell me exactly what is wrong, but just curious if someone was seen the generic error and what fixed it for them?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [install EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/install#get-the-net-core-cli-tools).

```
  - script: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef 
    displayName: 'dotnet install ef'
    workingDirectory: Source
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense though? dotnet should be installed on the pipeline server that is running our builds? Are you saying within the argument, that script needs to be added? I just wish if that were the case it would say that!

Comment: Yes i think in version 3 they took it out or what. SO what i am saying you need to run script "dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef  " to install before you run script to generate migration

Comment: @ttaylor27272727 found link to ms site. Also yes this script i copied from my own build.yaml file

Answer (score 0):

The editor.config file for stylecop was modified (not set up correctly) and was causing the migration build (local build and azure build itself were successful) to fail:

Below is what it was changed to fix it.

[image]